# regular expression for creating email

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am new in programming. I need to know the regular expression for creating of email

username@domain.extension

daniel@gmail.com

which is the length of username. Maximum number of characters. Minumum number of characters
which is the length of domain. Maximum number of characters. Minumum number of characters
which is the length of extension. Maximum number of characters. Minumum number of characters

Characters commonly accepted in every part of the email address

This is my expression regular

```
/^([a-z 0-9_\.-]{3,10})@([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})$/
```

I'd like improve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to create this from scratch start with reading the RFC for email

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822

Otherwise either stick to something simple like you have or use a gem that has already walked through that document.

https://github.com/validates-email-format-of/validates_email_format_of